# CSS - word-break in paragraph which each letter is in other element

Tags: html, css, word-break

I have got paragraph which each letter is in other element. For example:

```
<p>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>m</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>t</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>x</span>
    <span>t</span>
</p>
```

And I am trying to separate `Some` and `text`, but I see this:

```css
p {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 195px;
height: 200px;

}
```

```html
<p>
    <span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span>&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

How can I get something like this

```css
p {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 195px;
height: 200px;

}
```

```html
<p>
     Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text  
</p>
```

How can I break words in this paragraph and how to add `text-align: justify` effect?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You want divide by letter or what ?

Comment: Or you just want to divide the word "Some" and "Text" separtaly

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split by character using:

```
p span {display:inline-block;}
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 195px;
  height: 200px;
}

p span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

Otherwise, I think you would have to add a class to the `<span>`s with spaces so that the browser can know where to split words.

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 195px;
  height: 200px;
}

p span {
  display: inline;
}
  
p span.space {
  display: inline-block;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

**Edit:** I just realised that this will not allow justifying the text.  Instead, you can use:

```
p span.space:after {content: "\00200B";}
```

The only problem from there is that the last space in the line still has a width to it.

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 195px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: justify;
}

p span {
  display: inline;
}

p span.space:after {
    content: "\00200B";
}
```

```html
<p>
    <span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use it.